# send remote shell command and retrieve its output

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

Because I am unable to find a library that does the following I started heading out to write my own. I'm unable to find a solution for some problems, though, and hope that here maybe someone has a suggestion.

What I want is this. I send a normal shell command like `ls -al <some path>` and I want its output (stdout and stderr) in the same fashion and order as it would appear in my terminal emulator when writing that command. The catch is, that I don't want to run this shell command on the computer I'm currently using, but remotely via ssh or serial connection. To put it another way, when calling `ls -al <some path> 2>&1 >/tmp/out` I want to remotely receive the contents of `/tmp/out` without interruption or changes.

The problem is, with the serial connection always, with the ssh connection depending on your choice of library, that you get terminal command chars like `\x1b[K` mixed into your output. I am currently unable to find what exactly is creating these commands, why nothing is consuming them already, and I also don't know how I would go about consuming all of them myself (there are a lot, naive approaches won't work).

Why is it a problem to get special characters in your output? Well often you want to compare in your python code if the output has a string ala `if expected_output == output`, or at least use regular expressions. But there is nothing regular about when and why these characters appear. Sometimes a very simple command like `ls -al <something>` might result in the whole ssh connection breaking down (supposely because of these characters, but at least for sure because I don't know enough about all this to even understand what's the problem).

How would you go about solving the ultimate goal of sending commands remotely and receiving their output? How would you solve one of the mentioned subproblems (ssh connection that speaks to me like I would be a terminal, consuming randomly appearing special characters without interpreting them, etc)?

PS: There are many things I've already tried, but while writing I found them too many to list them all here. Nothing led to a desired end result, though. This really is a quite complex problem, especially because there seem to be things involved that are not traceable (like how many (pseudo-)terminals are actually involved) and others were never documented (some of the terminal handling seems to come from a time, where an actual typewriter was connected to the computer).

Answer (score 1):

You already have this type of library.Try

`Pexpect`.

You just need to spawn a pexpect child by making a ssh connection to the computer you want to make connection to.Then you can send commands and see ouput using `.before` functionality.

Example:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh admin@192.168.33.40')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline (mypassword)
child.expect('#') # or expect `$`.
child.sendline('<your command>')
child.expect('#')
print child.before
```

Ref:http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

P.S there's also `Paramiko` for the same though i havent used it.

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I was hoping from pexpect. But it doesn't get rid of the command characters. [Have a look here](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/137)

Comment: @erikb85 you know the command you sent.Its an easy task to replace it with `empty string` after you retreive it.Simple str.replace().

Comment: It is if there is only one such thing. There are many, they are different, and they come at random places.

Comment: @erikb85 a simple wrapper over `.before` will do the trick.Also it is much easier to conquer the problems rather than writing the whole library.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Maybe I just need to take a [list of definitions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) and replace them all with empty strings. The codes and interpretations vary, though. I hoped there would be a general purpose tool that does that already for all possible terminal types.

Comment: @erikb85 you can also try paramiko